# How can I construct a tree using this data structure

Tags: c#, recursion, tree

I have this tree structure, which a node may have multiple nodes.

```
public class Node
{
    public Node()
    {
        ChildLocations = new HashSet<Node>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int? ParentLocationId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Node> ChildLocations { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to add a list of `parent-child` value into this structure. like:

```
{1,A} -> {2,B}
{1,A} -> {3,C}
{1,A} -> {4,D}
{3,C} -> {5,E}
{3,C} -> {6,F}
```

to construct a tree looks like this:

```
          1A
        / |  \
    2B    3C   4D
         / \ 
       5E   6F
```

finally, it returns the `root` reference.

I have come out this solution. But I have no confidence with recursive part. It this correct?

```
public class Tree
{
    Node root;

    public Node Root
    {
        get { return root; }
    }

    public void Add(int parentId, string parentName, int childId, string childName)
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            root = new Node { Id = parentId, Name = parentName };
            root.ChildLocations.Add(new Node { Id = childId, Name = childName });
        }
        else
        {
            Add(root, parentId, parentName, childId, childName);
        }
    }

    private void Add(Node node, int parentId, string parentName, int childId, string childName)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (node.Id == parentId)
        {
            node.ChildLocations.Add(new Node { Id = childId, Name = childName });
            return;
        }
        foreach (var n in node.ChildLocations)
        {
            Add(n, parentId, parentName, childId, childName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll say it.. "What have you tried?"

Comment: You seem to have the class in place? What specific help do you need? Implementing an add function using recurrsion to find the parent node should be easy.

Comment: I think you need to specify how you expect it to be built. As it stands right now you could just hard code the creation of this tree, but that wouldn't be a very general purpose solution.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment to your question, this works to build the tree you require:

```
public Node BuildTree()
{
    var _1A = new Node() { Id = 1, Name = "A", };
    var _2B = new Node() { Id = 2, Name = "B", };
    var _3C = new Node() { Id = 3, Name = "C", };
    var _4D = new Node() { Id = 4, Name = "D", };
    var _5E = new Node() { Id = 5, Name = "E", };
    var _6F = new Node() { Id = 6, Name = "F", };
    _1A.ChildLocations.Add(_2B);
    _1A.ChildLocations.Add(_3C);
    _1A.ChildLocations.Add(_4D);
    _3C.ChildLocations.Add(_5E);
    _3C.ChildLocations.Add(_6F);
    return _1A;
}
```

But it's not very general purpose. Can you elaborate on your needs?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution which is not hard coded. I have edited my post and I'm not sure about my recursive method.

Comment: @null - Which is what I expected - I had hoped my answer would bring an update to the question. :-)